# Why I got error Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987 when open the form?

Tags: oracle-apex

I got this error when open the form :

```
Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - Unable to bind "P3_FIRST_NAME_E". 
Use double quotes for multi byte items or verify length of item is 30 bytes or less. 
Use v() syntax to reference items longer than 30 bytes. 
- Contact your application administrator. for Set Value.
```

I created a form and 2 items

P3_FIRST_NAME_A (arabic name)
P3_FIRST_NAME_E (english name)

I need when type arabic name and click enter read the corrsponding english name from the database .

I created dynamic action on item P3_FIRST_NAME_A (arabic name)

```
1- the Event = Change and items  P3_FIRST_NAME_A 
2- True action  = Set value 
3- set type = SQL statement 
4- SQL statement  = SELECT FORIEGN_NAME 
                    INTO :P3_FIRST_NAME_E 
                    FROM sys_dic_names WHERE native_name = :P3_FIRST_NAME_A ;
5- items to submit = P3_FIRST_NAME_A
6- Affected elements item = P3_FIRST_NAME_A
```

why when I open the form I got this error is the way I did correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution :

because I need to get data from database and from the server side

I changed the true action
from Set Value to
Execute Server-Side Code and the steps will be :

```
1- go to True action its value Show by default 

2- Select Execute Server-Side Code from Action list

3- In the settings the language PL/SQL 
 
4- In PL/SQL Code type the SQL statement : 

SELECT FORIEGN_NAME 
INTO :P3_FIRST_NAME_E 
FROM sys_dic_names 
WHERE native_name = :P3_FIRST_NAME_A 
and rownum=1;

5- In Items to Submit choose the item P3_FIRST_NAME_A

6- In Items to Return choose P3_FIRST_NAME_E
```

then its working as expected and get english name when type arabic name
also I added rownum=1 because if there is more than one name get only first one

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
    v_name varchar2(1000 char);
begin
    select FOREIGN_NAME  
    into v_name 
    from sys_dic_names 
    where native_name = :P3_FIRST_NAME_A;
    
    apex_util.set_session_state('P3_FIRST_NAME_E', v_name);
end;
```

Use PL/SQL statement and set the page item value like this.

Comment: its same SQL statement I used what is the difference ?